# Set big image to background

Tags: java, android

I got current wallpaper as below:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

now my current wallpaper  (1152 X 1536)

I try to put it as background to activity but in width does not as screen width.

```
ImageView rv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main);
rv.setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);
```

[image]

how I do it?

please help me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your RelativeLayout size is match_parent? 
 Then you can set Image fit to width side programmatically :

```
  int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(); //get window width
      yourIMG.getLayoutParams().width = width;   // set Image width = window width
```

Comment: we can use this solution if we work on image but on wallpaper and in my case (big size) not efficient thank you

Answer (score -2):

goto your xml for the current activity:

in that under the LinearLayout or Relative Layout add this line :

```
android:background = "@drawable/img_name"
```

and add the image to your drawable.

Comment: image background as current wallpaper